# MDL drawer does not fill the height of the page?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, material-design

I'm using Material Design Lite to add a fixed header and drawer to my Ruby on Rails app. As you can see in this [video](https://youtu.be/Bfv5aCX_DbE), when I navigate to another page, the drawer menu on the left hand side of the page does not fill the height of the page.

It remains at the abnormal height (even when I click another link) until I refresh the page. Can anyone figure out what's going on here? Here is the body of my application view:

```
<!-- Material design fixed header and drawer -->
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer
            mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">

      <!-- Add spacer to align search bar to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>

      <!-- Search bar -->
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                  mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
               for="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </label>
        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample"
                 id="fixed-header-drawer-exp">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Drawer menu  -->
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title"></span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<%= songs_path %>">Home</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="<%= new_song_path %>">Upload</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Page content -->
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content"><%= yield %></div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. 
Just add a

```
<div class="mdl-layout__container">
```

out of all the divs above. (don't forget to close the div by adding "</div>" at the end of the html)
I added  and it works too.